# Log4j2 RollingFileManager OnStartupTriggeringPolicy never rolls the file on startup

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I'm trying to get log4j2 (V2.11.1) to roll the existing log file at startup before it starts logging into a new file. My config is below. I'm using a RollingFileManager with a OnStartupTriggeringPolicy with minSize=0, which, according to the documentation should be sufficient.

However what i'm finding is that at startup, the `OnStartupTriggeringPolicy` class `initialize` method compares the timestamp of the log file to the JVM startup, and if the log file time is after the start-up time then it won't roll the file. If I step through the code then I see that at the point that check is made the file time is always after the JVM start time, because log4j2 appears to have already opened the file for writing at that point.

```
public void initialize(RollingFileManager manager) {
    if (manager.getFileTime() < JVM_START_TIME && manager.getFileSize() >= this.minSize) {
        if (this.minSize == 0L) {
            manager.setRenameEmptyFiles(true);
        }

        manager.skipFooter(true);
        manager.rollover();
        manager.skipFooter(false);
    }
}
```

Is this a bug or am I just doing something wrong?

**EDIT:** Have raised a bug report with Log4j2 team ([LOG4J2-2517](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2517)). Initial discussions lean heavily in favour of this actually being a bug.

log4j2.json:

```
{
    "configuration": {
        "appenders": {
            "Console": {
                "name": "Console",
                "PatternLayout": {
                    "pattern": "%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%c{2}] [%t]%n[%p] : %m%n"
                }
            },
            "RollingFile": {
                "name": "RollingFile",
                "fileName": "logs/orchestrator.log",
                "filePattern": "logs/orchestrator-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz",
                "append": false,
                "PatternLayout": {
                    "pattern": "%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%c{2}] [%t]%n[%p] : %m%n"
                },
                "Policies": {
                    "OnStartupTriggeringPolicy": {
                        "minSize" : 0
                    },
                    "SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy": {
                        "size": "50 MB"
                    }
                },
                "DefaultRolloverStrategy": {
                    "max": "10"
                }
            }
        },
        "loggers": {
            "root": {
                "level": "info",
                "AppenderRef": [
                    {"ref": "RollingFile", "level": "INFO"},
                    {"ref": "Console", "level": "ERROR"}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed as a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2517?focusedCommentId=16731684&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16731684), fixed in the as-yet-unreleased V2.11.2 of Log4j2.